# Trying to solve a maze (wavefront algorithm)

Tags: python, algorithm, wavefront

Hello I am trying to write a maze solving program in python using the waveform algorithm ([explained here](http://www.societyofrobots.com/programming_wavefront.shtml)). I am using nested loops to loop through a matrix and change the numbers like [in this animated gif.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuxDu.gif)

However it only seems to be looping through the first row of my matrix and not moving on to the rest. I have been staring at this thing for quite a while and I'm hoping that getting some fresh eyes on it will help.

Thanks, Logan

```
floorMap = [[000,000,000,000,000,999,999,999,999,999],
           [000,000,999,000,999,000,000,000,999,999],
           [000,000,999,000,999,000,000,000,999,999],
           [000,000,000,000,999,000,000,000,999,999],
           [999,000,000,000,999,000,999,999,999,999],
           [999,000,000,000,000,000,999,000,000,999],
           [999,000,000,000,999,999,999,000,000,999],
           [999,000,999,000,000,000,999,000,000,999],
           [999,000,999,999,999,000,000,000,000,999],
           [999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,000,000]]
robotX=0
robotY=0

goalX=9
goalY=9

currentNum=0

wall=999
uncalculated=000

floorMap[robotX][robotY]=1


def changeSurroundings(X, Y):
    #left
    if(floorMap[X-1][Y]==000):
        floorMap[X-1][Y]=currentNum   
    #right 
    if(floorMap[X+1][Y]==000):
        floorMap[X+1][Y]=currentNum  
    #up
    if(floorMap[X][Y-1]==000):
        floorMap[X][Y-1]=currentNum  
    #down
    if(floorMap[X][Y+1]==000):
        floorMap[X][Y+1]=currentNum    

def printMap():
    i=0
    while(i<len(floorMap)):
        print floorMap[i]
        print ""
        i+=1
    print ""
    print ""



#------------------THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS--------------

while(floorMap[goalX][goalY]==0):
    x=0
    y=0
    while(x<len(floorMap[0])):
        while(y<len(floorMap)):
            if(floorMap[x][y] > 000 and floorMap[x][y] < 999):
                currentNum=floorMap[x][y]+1
                changeSurroundings(x,y)
                printMap()

            y+=1
        x+=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x=0
y=0
while(x<len(floorMap[0])):
    while(y<len(floorMap)):
        ...
        y+=1
    x+=1
```

The problem here is that once the inner loop has exhausted the `y` values, it will be exhausted until the outer loop has completed, since you don't reset `y` for each inner loop.

Simply move the `y=0` line into the outer loop:

```
x=0
while(x<len(floorMap[0])):
    y=0
    while(y<len(floorMap)):
        ...
        y+=1
    x+=1
```